# SharePoint split content database - mergecontentdbs

Tags: sharepoint, database, content-management, database-administration

I'm splitting a SharePoint content database and running into a problem with the stsadm mergecontentdbs command. I'm pretty positive it is an error in my command, which is as follows:

```
stsadm -o mergecontentdbs -url http://sharepoint:15741 -sourcedatabasename "SharePoint_AdminContent_5b924b0e-e1ef-46c5-b6c0-d3b4beb4e3b9" -destinationdatabasename SP_AdminContent_02 -operation 3 -filename mergedcontentdbs.xml
```

The "mergedcontentdbs.xml" file was creately without a problem with stsadm enumsites and does appear to contain the appropriate urls. The SP_AdminContent_02 database was created using a script based on the existing database. The error that I get is "Missing operation name or the operation name is invalid." Thanks for any help anyone can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What service pack level of sharepoint are you on? mergecontentdbs was introduced in 2007 SP1 so if you aren't up to that level yet it won't exist.

If this is the problem (you aren't upgraded to SP1 or higher yet) there is a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939035) that can be applied to add mergecontentdbs.

Comment: That would appear to be the problem. It looks like this is a much older version than I had realized. Thanks very much!